# What does "Suicide after choosing a player class" mean?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In Options -> Multiplayer -> Advanced there's an option called "Suicide after choosing a player class". What does it do? Is it a good idea to check/uncheck?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you choose to change your role, if you have 'Suicide after choosing player class' enabled, you will die immediately and start to respawn as your new role. If disabled, the class change won't take place until you die in battle (or the round ends).

Note: this death will be counted as a Suicide, you if you are one to worry about your kill/death ratio, I'd disable it.

Comment: Is there a backside to die immediately? Like losing points in the game? Saw your note about kill/death ratio, but is that all?

Comment: No.. no other penalty... But don't enable it. If you want to change class quickly, why not just do a kamikaze run at the enemy and try to take one or more out...?

Comment: The reason being is that sometimes you need to switch classes to be effective *right now*. Example: "I'm not doing my team much good as a spy vs. a team with 7 pyros. I'm not likely to get much luckier this time around. Might as well switch."

Comment: @JN Web: If you are a Spy against pyros, a suicidal charge will take just a few extra seconds (on top of the 15 or so you have to wait to respawn and the 30 seconds it takes to get back to the 'front line') and you might just take an enemy out in the process (or even just distract them to aid your teammates). 

Very rarely will suicide and a 45 second wait be needed that desperately compared to a suicide run, one dead/wounded enemy and a 50 second wait.

Comment: If you're in the spawning area the switch is immediate.

Comment: Open console (~ default), type 'explode'.

Comment: There are some disadvantages, but they are all linked to dying, like loosing you KS or Uber, or how many Heads you have stolen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on class x, you can choose another class to spawn with. This will happen on your death. You can speed up playing that new class bhy selecting 'suicide blabla'.